# Can't access element inside success ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm putting an ajax call inside an ajax call, but in the second, the element is not being recognized, example:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'controleFatAcoes.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        acao: 'validaenviofat',
        id_cliente: cli.id_cliente,
        dt_fat: cli.id_fat
    },
    success: function(data)  {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controleFatAcoes.php',
            data: {id_cliente: cli.id_cliente, 
                  id_fat: cli.id_fat, acao: 'getdadosnf'},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(dados) {
                    **$('#templateEmpresa').html(dados.empresa);**
            }
        )};
});
```

When I run a `console.log($('#templateEmpresa'))`, I get:

```
[context: document, selector: "#templateEmpresa", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
```

Comment: Can you paste the ajax() result header here? So that we can properly see the structure of the ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code out:**
Might be a problem of scope given that you are executing the second ajax call inside the success function of the first ajax call.

```
var firstajaxsuccess = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: 'controleFatAcoes.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        acao: 'validaenviofat',
        id_cliente: cli.id_cliente,
        dt_fat: cli.id_fat
    },
    success: function(data)  {
         firstajaxsuccess = 1;
    }
});
if(firstajaxsuccess){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controleFatAcoes.php',
            data: {id_cliente: cli.id_cliente, 
                  id_fat: cli.id_fat, acao: 'getdadosnf'},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(dados) {
                    **$('#templateEmpresa').html(dados.empresa);**
            }
        )};
}
```

Comment: The div #fatTemplate is inside a textarea, because i'm using the plugin tinyMce...

Comment: You may also consider saving the $('#templateEmpresa') object in a variable before accessing it in your AJAX function.